# Python - How to close a port left open?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sockets

I have a process which at times is opening a port and then not closing it (I'm on Windows 10).

What is the best way to close this via Python? The port number is 1300 and will not change.

I know this can be done manually via command line by killing the PID, however I would like to keep it all in one easy to use batch file.

Comment: If the process that's keeping the port open is still running, there's nothing you can do externally other than killing the process.

Comment: @jasonharper that doesn't seem to be the case—the free [CurrPorts](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html) utility says that it can close specific connections not belonging to itself.  See the section "Closing a Connection From Command-Line" of the linked page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  [the psutil](https://code.google.com/archive/p/psutil/) module.

```
from psutil import process_iter
from signal import SIGKILL

for proc in process_iter():
    for conns in proc.get_connections(kind='inet'):
        if conns.laddr[1] == 1300:
            proc.send_signal(SIGKILL) 
            continue
```

Otherwise, you should just call `kill`  [from subprocess.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python)

Comment: AttributeError: 'Process' object has no attribute 'get_connections' :\

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's psutil library to find and terminate the process using port 1300. Here's how you can do it:

```py
import psutil

def close_port(port):
    for conn in psutil.net_connections(kind='inet'):
        if conn.laddr.port == port:
            print(f"Closing port {port} by terminating PID {conn.pid}")
            process = psutil.Process(conn.pid)
            process.terminate()

close_port(1300)
```

Make sure you have psutil installed (`pip install psutil`). Then you can run this script to close the process using port 1300. You can easily integrate this script into your batch file.